# Error when run flowvisor in Ubuntu 18 to make multiple floodlight controller?

Tags: dual-boot, server, windows-10

I tried to run flowvisor in mininet,

- first I create custom topology in mininet
- second I wrote this command

  ```
  sudo -u flowvisor fvconfig generate /etc/flowvisor /config.json
  ```

the error was appeared

> ```
> sudo :unknown user :flowvisor
> sudo :unable to initialize policy plugin
> ```

Comment: Please run `man sudo` to learn how `sudo` works. `-u` let you run a command as other user, in this case "flowvisor". Please provide more information about the steps you are following.

Comment: Hi @Pablo Bianchi first I write command in the Ubuntu 14 terminal sudo mn — custom ./mininet/custom/flowvisor_scripts/flowvisor_topo.py — link tc —controller remote — mac — arp then I opened another terminal to write the command sudo -u flowvisor fvconfig generate /etc/flowvisor/config.json

Comment: I tried in Ubuntu 18 dual boot and on Ubuntu 14 on my vm

Comment: Please **update your post** (read about [Markdown syntax](https://commonmark.org/help/)) with the info (better if you can provide an official flowvisor link) about the steps you are following. You are getting that error because user flowvisor doesn't exist (`getent passwd | grep flowvisor` will not return any line).